# Extract text between two varying sections using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and I was trying to do my first project: webscraping a scientific journal to search for specific topics of interest. In this case, I would like to search for all papers published under **HOW WE TEACH** for example in this webpage: https://www.physiology.org/toc/advances/43/2

The problem is that the papers are not children of **HOW WE TEACH** and are placed between two headers (the second of which may vary depending on the magazine issue). Is there a way to extract all text between two consecutive headers?

[image: see image of what I want to extract here]

Comment: If you can put in words what you mean (as well as provide a picture to subsitute for a thousand ;-), you can address it. Couldn't you use the html DOM property `nextSibling` of your first toc header and continue as long as the nextSibling is not a toc header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:contains` with bs4 4.7.1 + and filter out the sibling divs that come after the next `h2` from the `h2` of interest. You then have all the relevant parent `div`s and can loop and extract whatever info you want and format how you like.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.physiology.org/toc/advances/43/2')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
divs = soup.select('h2:contains("HOW WE TEACH") ~ div:not(h2:contains("ILLUMINATIONS") ~ div)')
for div in divs:
    print(div.get_text(' '), '\n')
```

If you don't know what the next h2 header will be then you can generalise with:

```
divs = soup.select('h2:contains("HOW WE TEACH") ~ div:not(h2:contains("HOW WE TEACH") ~ h2 ~ div)')
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Roadowl already said you can find `<h2>` with text "HOW WE TEACH" and then use `next_siblings` (or `next_sibling()`) to get next items. And you have to check if next item is `<h2>`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.physiology.org/toc/advances/43/2'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('h2', text='HOW WE TEACH')

for x in item.next_siblings:
   if x.name == 'h2':
        break

   print('\n>>>', x.name, '<<<\n')
   print(x.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

The following allows for what I wanted to do for now (there is still some typos on the final csv file, but at least it works!). Now I will start working on creating a loop for searching on all "issues" webpages.

Cheers,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.physiology.org/toc/advances/43/2')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

containers = soup.select('h2:contains("HOW WE TEACH") ~ div:not(h2:contains("HOW WE TEACH") ~h2 ~ div)')

containers

containers[0]

#Create file
filename = "papers4.csv"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8')
headers = "title, first_author, abstract, hiperligacao, \n"
f.write("headers")

container = containers[0]

#Get title
title = container.h4.a.text

#Get first author
first_author = container.ul.li.text.strip()

#Get abstract
abstract = container.find("div", {"class": "accordion__content toc-item__abstract"})
text_abstract = abstract.p.text.strip()

# Get URL
url = container.p.a.text.strip()

for container in containers:
    title_container = container.h4.a.text
    first_author = container.ul.li.text.strip()
    abstract = container.find("div", {"class": "accordion__content toc-item__abstract"})
    abstract_text = abstract.p.text.strip()
    linkes = container.p.a.text.strip()


    print("title: " + title_container)
    print("first_author: " + first_author)
    print("abstract: " + abstract_text)
    print("hiperligacao: " + linkes) 

f.write(title_container + "|" + first_author + "|" + abstract_text + "|" + linkes + "\n")
f.close()
```